# LSTM TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

Code:

```
parameters1 = len(data.columns)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(24, input_shape = parameters1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(12))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=\['accuracy'\])
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I think is because of my `input_shape` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `input_shape` expects a `tuple` and not an `int` which is returned by the `len` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply reshape the input and add 1 dimension to it

```
input = input.reshape( input.shape, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input_shape` must be in the form of a list/tuple and you pass a single int.
`parameters1 = tuple(len(data.columns))` is what is expected.